# Kendo Grid - How to display Header Text in First column

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My requirement is to display header as part of first column and then again actual header and then the value of columns, like 4X4 matrix, not sure how I can display headers in column of kendo grid.
[image]

Comment: This is little uncleat what you want. Do you want something like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders ? And the difference is that you want to have two headers in single column - not multiple. If not can you do any drawing or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it. If it just styling issue you can just add the `k-grid-header` class to fist column. In JavaScipt grid you can do this this way:

```
columns: [
    {
        field: "FieldName",
        attributes: {
            "class": "k-grid-header"
        }
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Here is working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/obApu

But If you want some header functions in "header column" like sorting or filtering that is more complicated and you have to implement by your own.

Comment: Added a screenshot, try to achive something like shown in second pic